# URLSession in Swift 3 - URLAuthenticationChallenge

Tags: ios, swift, urlsession, authenticationchallenge

Below is the snippet for making request.

```
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        let configurationId = String(format: "NetworkManager%d", UInt16(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(UINT16_MAX))))
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: configurationId)
        let session = Foundation.URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.current)
        let task = session.downloadTask(with: request)
        task.resume()
```

While making this request, the authentication challenge methods as described below are not getting called.

```
@nonobjc func urlSession(_ session: Foundation.URLSession, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: (Foundation.URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Swift.Void)

@nonobjc func urlSession(_ session: Foundation.URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler:  (Foundation.URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Swift.Void)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following header slightly different from the ones you listed in your question.

```
open func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {
    //handle challenge here.
}
```

Comment: do you have some pointers of how to properly use that function?